# Showing $x = x' \implies f(x) = f(x')$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

My understanding is that a function mapping a set $A$ to a set $B$ is defined as a relation $f \subseteq A \times B$ such that for every $x \in X$ there exists a unique $y \in Y$ such that $(x, y) \in f$.

Is it possible to use this definition to show that for any $x, x' \in X$, $x = x' \implies f(x) = f(x')$?

Comment: You don't need that. substitution of the two variables is enough. When  those variables are equal, the terms are equal and thus the result.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(x)$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I'm using $f(x)$ to denote the unique $y \in Y$ with $(x, y) \in f$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)x=x' ("x" and "x'"denote the same element of A) ;(2)f(x)= f(x) (an axiom for equality or obvious ) .When variables denote the same object one may substitute one variable for the other in any occurrence  which is free for substitution ( not in the scope of a quantifier ) Thus substituting "x'" for "x" for the second occurrence  in (2) gives
f(x)=f(x') as desired .

Comment: Is this substitution property of equality an axiom?

Comment: This substitution rule (1) together with (2) A=A (A any denoting term) are the axioms for an axiomatic treatment of = (equality ) in the  logic used for mathematics . However to say "A=B"  ( "A" and "B" any terms) means that these terms denote the exact same object  so (1) and (2) should be obvious and you should use them freely ,they are very useful in making things clear . Good questions .

Comment: I see, many thanks for your answer. I also found a helpful document by Terry Tao which I'll leave a link to [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/logic.pdf) for anyone else like me who might want to read more about this.